# Is it possible to use Magento checkout on non Magento site

Tags: magento, e-commerce, checkout

I'm working on a non-magento e-commerce website, created with Symfony because standard e-commerce framework are too much restrictive towards the website specifications.

However i would like to know if it is possible to use Magento checkout solution as standalone because this part of the framework is compliant to the specifications.

I haven't found any attempt of that but since Magento is a quite modular i am wondering if there is any chance of doing this.

Comment: In your case, I would have started from the opposite side: using Symfony into Magento.
Anyway, in my opinion there are no specification that cannot be achieved with Magento itself, just because its modularity.

Comment: In fact my problem in rather in Magento's way to work with databases, products and users. In my case, users have to be able to create products and put them on sale, and i couldn't find a way to do it in pure Magento that would take less time that recreating an e-commerce solution bounded to my needs with Symfony.

Comment: For these features you can find many Magento extensions that can help you (If you don't want to develop your own).
Here is a discussion on Magento forum that should reflect your needs.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/74670/

Comment: Just to complete the answer, this extension should fit your needs, but I never tried it before.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/marketplace.html

Answer (score 1):

yes its possible by using magento soap api

Here's [a link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html) for reference.

Comment: That looks great but does it mean i don't need to create Magento tables ? everything will be stored through SOAP ?

Comment: @ibi0tux U need magento tables, do install magento set up on your server, and use soap api to integrate the magento tables from front end

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. Actually i don't want to use Magento tables, that's why i wanted to know.

Comment: @ibi0tux than where you want to create that products

Comment: In fact, i didn't want to create Magento products, using a custom implementation. I would like to be able to transform my own cart into a magento cart only for checkout process.